# Opening images on NodeJS and finding out width/height

Tags: javascript, image, node.js

How do I get the equivalent of a "new Image()" (and then myImage.src... etc), but on NodeJS?

Comment: Your best bet might be to figure out how to integrate the ImageMagick (or GraphicsMagick) C runtime into Node.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's [node-imagemagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick), (you'll need to have ImageMagick, obviously).

```
var im = require('imagemagick');
im.identify('kittens.jpg', function(err, features){
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(features)
  // { format: 'JPEG', width: 3904, height: 2622, depth: 8 }
})
```

Comment: Zerosocrates, can I have your children? HAHA Sorry, I haven't slept and I got stomachache :( but at least I'm programming and there's pizza.

Comment: @john-flatness Any idea how to do that in memory?

Answer (score 23):

Using `imagemagick` for this is very overkill since you only want to read the header of the file and check the dimensions. `image-size` is a pure javascript implementation of said feature which is very easy to use.

https://github.com/image-size/image-size

```
var sizeOf = require('image-size')

sizeOf('images/funny-cats.png', function (err, dimensions) {
  if (err) throw err

  console.log(dimensions.width, dimensions.height)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/nodeca/probe-image-size that should help. Small + sync/async modes + urls support.

```
var probe = require('probe-image-size');

// Get by URL
//
probe('http://example.com/image.jpg', function (err, result) {
  console.log(result); // => { width: xx, height: yy, type: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg', wUnits: 'px', hUnits: 'px' }
});

// From the stream
//
var input = require('fs').createReadStream('image.jpg');

probe(input, function (err, result) {
  console.log(result);
  // => { width: xx, height: yy, type: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg', wUnits: 'px', hUnits: 'px' }

  // terminate input, depends on stream type,
  // this example is for fs streams only.
  input.destroy();
});

// From a Buffer
//
var data = require('fs').readFileSync('image.jpg');

console.log(probe.sync(data)); // => { width: xx, height: yy, type: 'jpg', mime: 'image/jpeg', wUnits: 'px', hUnits: 'px' }
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of this code.