# nodejs read image data

Tags: image, node.js, jpeg

Is there any library to read image data of a jpeg ?

I would like to get the pixel of a jpeg.

I only find library like node-jpeg or gm but they don't provide images data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do this with the [node-imagemagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick) module. 
(see [Opening images on NodeJS and finding out width/height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530946/opening-images-on-nodejs-and-finding-out-width-height)).

Also, if you prefer accessing the EXIF metadata, there is [node-exif](https://github.com/gomfunkel/node-exif).

Comment: Hmm but I would like to get the RGB values... Sorry I didn't say it in the question.

Comment: Is it possible to get the width and height of the image as well?

Answer (score 0):

There are also `exifr` and `exiftool-vendored`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/exifr

https://www.npmjs.com/package/exiftool-vendored

Answer (score -1):

npm got a package that can extract pixel data in rgba, maybe it could help:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-image-pixels

Comment: This module is used in the client side only, OP is asking for a Node.js solution.