# Get the width and height of an image in node.js

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to get the width and height of an image in node.js (on the server side, not the client side)? I need to find the width and height of an image in a node.js library that I'm writing.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate (and someone found an answer already): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530946/opening-images-on-nodejs-and-finding-out-width-height

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes this is possible but you will need to install [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) or [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).

I have used both and I can recommend GraphicsMagick it's lot faster.

Once you have installed both the program and it's [module](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) you would do something like this to get the width and height.

```
gm = require('gm');

// obtain the size of an image
gm('test.jpg')
.size(function (err, size) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('width = ' + size.width);
    console.log('height = ' + size.height);
  }
});
```

Comment: In this case, how can I write a function that returns `size.width` for a given image, and invoke that function outside of the callback?

Comment: Also, here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540405/how-can-i-specify-the-order-in-which-node-js-functions-are-evaluated

Comment: I have provided an answer to other question you linked to.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using an image library in pure JS?

Comment: This is a great example of why you should always use curly brackets, only the first `console.log` is covered by the `if` statement.

Comment: How would I go about using a remote URL?

Comment: Oliver, the link in the answer below this one shows an example of getting the dimensions of a remote URL.

Comment: can anyone tell us how to get the remote URL image size please ? with 'https://' ??

Answer (score 177):

Installing `GraphicsMagick` or `ImageMagick` isn't at all needed, determining the dimensions of a image is as easy as looking at the header. `image-size` is a pure javascript implementation of said feature which is very easy to use.

https://github.com/netroy/image-size

```
var sizeOf = require('image-size');
sizeOf('images/funny-cats.png', function (err, dimensions) {
  console.log(dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer simply because gm/im have much more overhead than needed for this task.

Comment: There is a [bug in image-size](https://github.com/netroy/image-size/issues/37). I just experienced it in production. GraphicsMagick does not have the same bug.

Comment: Not at all. image-size gives "Corrupt JPG, exceeded buffer limits" error on big jpg files

Comment: This is indeed a very good solution. And for those who require only a tiny bit of the logic for a specific format, for example, the library is very easy to extract and reduce.

Comment: If you are trying to use this in a context which doesn't allow `fs` or `path` imports, try using the `buffer-image-size` library instead ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71922563/2738164)).  It explicitly forks `image-size` and removes those two dependencies.  Very helpful for usage in Next.js static contexts.

Answer (score 24):

https://github.com/nodeca/probe-image-size

More interesting problem is "how to detect image size without full file download from remote server". `probe-image-size` will help. Of course, it supports local streams too.

It's written in pure JS and does not need any heavy dependencies (ImageMagick and so on).

Comment: This should be the newly accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Easiest way to do this with multer using buffer-image-size**

I have used [buffer-image-size](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer-image-size) to validate the image dimensions. I need to validate the exact image size before uploading it to the bucket.

```
var sizeOf = require('buffer-image-size');
var dimensions = sizeOf(yourImageBuffer);
console.log(dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
```

ex:

Router.js

```
Router.post('/upload_image',
         multerUpload.single('image'),     // multer upload configuration
         imageDimensionHandler(500,200),   // here I validate image dimension
         upload_image_controller           // controller function
       );
```

here is my middleware that I used after `multerUpload.single('image')` middleware.

imageDimensionHandler.js ( middleware )

```
const sizeOf = require('buffer-image-size');

const imageDimensionHandler = (width, height) => (async (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.file) {
        const fileBuffer = req.file.buffer;
        var dimensions = sizeOf(fileBuffer);

        if (width == dimensions.width && height == dimensions.height) {
            next();
        } else {
            throw new Error(`expected image size is ${condition.width} x ${condition.height} pixel.`);
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Note: please ignore it if you don't find it appropriate for you.

Answer (score 2):

Calipers is another pure Javascript library that can determine the dimensions of images.

https://github.com/calipersjs/calipers

Answer (score 2):

I used Jimp: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp
npm install --save jimp

```
const jimage1 = await Jimp.read(imgBuffer);
const jimage2 = await Jimp.read(imgUrl);
const width = jimage1.bitmap.width;
```

It's effectively a wrapper for pixel-match

Answer (score 0):

```
var sizeOf = require('image-size');
    sizeOf(my_file_item.completeFilename, function (err, dimensions) {
        try{
          if(!err){
            let image_dimensions = dimensions || "";
            let width = 200; // we want 200 
            let height = parseInt(width/(image_dimensions.width/image_dimensions.height));


          }else{

          }
          // console.log(ex);
        }catch(ex){

        }
      });
```