# How to get image resolution data from uploaded image in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express 3 to make a http server which uploads the image in a designated folder but I am not able to get the image resolution in the req object . 
I tried looking in req.files and req.files.images and req.files.headers but I could not find that information . 
How can I get the resoultion of the uploaded image .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See solution here: [Opening images on NodeJS and finding out width/height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530946/opening-images-on-nodejs-and-finding-out-width-height)

```
var im = require('imagemagick');
im.identify(req.files.images.path, function(err, features){
  if (err) throw err
   console.log(features)
   // { format: 'JPEG', width: 3904, height: 2622, depth: 8 }
 })
```

Make sure you have imagemagick included and installed in your project.

Comment: I am getting 
Tue, 24 Dec 2013 01:00:25 GMT uncaughtException spawn ENOENT
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34) and my application exits . Anyways I get "/home/bhanuc/win/winter/crowd-sourcing/public/uploads/56943-nghb7g.jpg" from req.files.image.path

Comment: You need to install imagick CLI, http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php , also under your project directory run `npm install imagemagick`

Comment: Can we install it in ubuntu ?

Comment: That would be simplest, inside your terminal run: sudo apt-get install imagemagick