# How to get meta data of an image like height, width uploaded on express node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, buffer, multipartform-data

I am using node js express and on front end React. I am uploading image and in node want to read its metadata and save into database. but the problem is that I am unble to get height and the width of the image?? I have used Multer literary to get metadata of file

### **frontend Code** I am uploading image

```
     let imgdata = new FormData();
                       imgdata.append('file', file)
                        let headers= {
                      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                                axios.post(`${API_URL}images/add`,imgdata  
    , headers    )
                        .then( res=> {
                            console.log(res)
                        })
                        .catch( err => {
                            console.log(err)
                        })
```

### **Node js Code:**

```
    const express = require('express');
    const images = express.Router()
    const cors = require('cors')
    images.use(cors())

    var multer = require('multer')
    var upload = multer().single('file')

    images.post('/add', function (req, res) {
      upload(req, res, function (err) {
        res.send(req.file)
      })
    })
    module.exports = images
```

## **This is the result what i get from this**

```
    { fieldname: 'file',
      originalname: 'aa.jpg',
      encoding: '7bit',
      mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
      buffer:
       <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 48 00 48 00 
       00 ff e1 0e 48 45 78 69 66 00 00 49 49 2a 00 08 00 00 00 08 00 0f 
        01 02 00 12 00 00 00 6e 00 ... >,
      size: 748212 }
```

### from above data I want to read the height and the width of data How can I??

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530946/opening-images-on-nodejs-and-finding-out-width-height